# C program crashing

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I have found a challenge on Reddit to make a program which given a number `A`, will find the smallest possible value of `B+C`, if `B*C = A`. Here `A`, `B`, and `C` must all be positive integers. For some reason, my program crashes and I can't find the reason why. I'm still a beginner in `C` and I'm still trying to learn the language. Any help and tips would be helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXDIM 128

int factor1[MAXDIM];
int factor2[MAXDIM];
int sum[MAXDIM];
int counter;

void factors(int a);
void sumf(const int *f1,const int *f2);
int smallestSum(const int *s);

int main(void){
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    factors(a);
    sumf(&factor1[0],&factor2[0]);
    printf("%d => %d",a,smallestSum(&sum[0]));
    return 0;
}

void factors(int a){
    int i=1;
    int j=0;
    while(i<a/2){
        if(a%i==0){
            /*two arrays which hold all factors 
            e.g. 
            a = 10 
            factor1 = 1 2
            factor2 = 10 5
            */
            factor1[j]=i;
            factor2[j]=a/i;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    counter=i; // counter which holds length of factor arrays, used in other functions
}

void sumf(const int *f1,const int *f2){
    int i=0;
    while(i<counter+1){
        // array which holds sums of factor1 and factor2
        sum[i]=*(f1+i)+*(f2+i);
        i++;
    }
}

int smallestSum(const int *s){
    int min;
    int i=0;
    min=*s;
    while(i<counter+1){
        if(*(s+i)<min){
            min=*(s+i);
        }
    }
    return min; 
}
```

Comment: First of all, determine where it crashes. do some printf statements like printf("test1"); then you will know where to look for the mistake

Comment: what is your input? If I input 25 I get an infinite loop in `smallestSum`

Comment: In the `while(i<counter+1)` loop of `smallestSum`, neither you are changing `i` not `counter`. If the condition `i<counter+1` is true, its an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possible crash source is here:

```
counter=i;
```

it should be:

```
counter=j;
```

`j` is keeping factors array index, not `i`. Another crash source is here:

```
void sumf(const int *f1,const int *f2){
    int i=0;
    while(i<counter+1){ // <-- here
         ...
    }
}
```

Because you have `counter` element, it should be like this:

```
while(i<counter)
```

`smallestSum()` has same problem too. In addition yo have forgotten to increase `i` in the loop in `smallestSum()`.

I should say these are bugs that I found and there may be more that I'm missing. But generally this code can be much better when you get more experience.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even notice I hadn't put increment in smallestSum().

Answer (score 0):

To start off with, in smallestSum i will be forever 0, so it will run forever.
I think you need to do i++. But I would think you have more bugs in there.
What input are you providing when running it ?

Answer (score 0):

When you debug your program use debugger and breakpoints. It also helps to print out intermediate results to see if the algorithm works properly.
Doing so you can notice that `counter` gets initialized to improper 
value all the time. You would notice that `smallestSum()` function never ends because the loop never breaks. You need to increase `i` at the proper place inside that function. Check if your condition `while(i<counter+1)` is correct, since loop starts from `0` comparing to `counter` is enough.

The program works after all those corrections:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXDIM 128

int factor1[MAXDIM];
int factor2[MAXDIM];
int sum[MAXDIM];

int counter;

void factors(int a);
void sumf(const int *f1, const int *f2);
int smallestSum(const int *s);

void factors(int a){
    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;     
    while( i < a/2 ){

        if( a%i == 0){
            /*two arrays which hold all factors 
            e.g. 
            a = 10 
            factor1 = 1 2
            factor2 = 10 5
            */
            factor1[j] = i;
            factor2[j] = a/i;

            printf("i=%d j=%d factor1[j]=%d factor12[j]=%d\n",i,j,factor1[j],factor2[j]  );

            j++;
        }           
        i++;
    }

    counter = j; // counter which holds length of factor arrays
}

void sumf(const int *f1, const int *f2){

    int i = 0; 
    while(i<counter){
        // array which holds sums of factor1 and factor2
        sum[i] = *(f1+i) + *(f2+i);

         printf("i=%d sum %d %d %d\n", i,  sum[i], *(f1+i), *(f2+i) );
        i++;
    }
}

int smallestSum(const int *s){

    int min;
    int i = 0;
    min =*s;

    while(i<counter){

        if( *(s+i) < min){
             min= *(s+i);
        }
        i++;
    }

    return min;
}

int main(void){

    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);

    factors(a);

    sumf( &factor1[0], &factor2[0] );

    printf("For a=%d the smallest sum is => %d", a, smallestSum(&sum[0]));    
    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
90                                                                                                                                             
i=1 j=0 factor1[j]=1 factor12[j]=90                                                                                                            
i=2 j=1 factor1[j]=2 factor12[j]=45                                                                                                            
i=3 j=2 factor1[j]=3 factor12[j]=30                                                                                                            
i=5 j=3 factor1[j]=5 factor12[j]=18                                                                                                            
i=6 j=4 factor1[j]=6 factor12[j]=15                                                                                                            
i=9 j=5 factor1[j]=9 factor12[j]=10                                                                                                            
i=10 j=6 factor1[j]=10 factor12[j]=9                                                                                                           
i=15 j=7 factor1[j]=15 factor12[j]=6                                                                                                           
i=18 j=8 factor1[j]=18 factor12[j]=5                                                                                                           
i=30 j=9 factor1[j]=30 factor12[j]=3                                                                                                           
i=0 sum 91 1 90                                                                                                                                
i=1 sum 47 2 45                                                                                                                                
i=2 sum 33 3 30                                                                                                                                
i=3 sum 23 5 18                                                                                                                                
i=4 sum 21 6 15                                                                                                                                
i=5 sum 19 9 10                                                                                                                                
i=6 sum 19 10 9                                                                                                                                
i=7 sum 21 15 6                                                                                                                                
i=8 sum 23 18 5                                                                                                                                
i=9 sum 33 30 3                                                                                                                                
For a=90 the smallest sum is => 19
```